# 403 error on configuring new wordpress install

Tags: wordpress, ubuntu, apache2

I am using Apache2 and ubuntu. Before my attempt to install wordpress on my server, i was able to open my domain in browser. But after the commands that i wrote below, i can not open it. When i browse my domain it is giving 403 error

> Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource.

I used the commands below while i was installing wordpress. And now, i am wondering how to fix this situation. And which files or other things should i check. Thank you.

**First Commands That I Used For In My Terminal**

```
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz
mysql -u root -p
CREATE DATABASE wordpress; Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
CREATE USER wordpressuser@localhost; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
SET PASSWORD FOR wordpressuser@localhost= PASSWORD("password"); Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO wordpressuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'password'; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
FLUSH PRIVILEGES; Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
cp ~/wordpress/wp-config-sample.php ~/wordpress/wp-config.php
sudo nano ~/wordpress/wp-config.php
// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** // /** The name of the database for WordPress */ define('DB_NAME', 'wordpress'); /** MySQL database username */ define('DB_USER', 'wordpressuser'); /** MySQL database password */ define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
sudo rsync -avP ~/wordpress/ /var/www/
cd /var/www/
sudo chown username:www-data /var/www -R sudo chmod g+w /var/www -R
sudo apt-get install php5-gd
```

**As These Commands Above Didnt Work for me I used Other Commands Below After Deleting Wordpress Directory**

```
cd /var/www/html
sudo wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
sudo tar xvfz latest.tar.gz
sudo chown www-data.www-data wordpress/
```

**Those Commands Also Didnt Work For Me So I Added The Other Ones Below**

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/www/html/example.com/src/
cd /var/www/html/example.com/src/
chmod 755 /var/www/html
chmod 750 /var/www
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/example.com/
sudo wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
sudo -u www-data tar -xvf latest.tar.gz
sudo mv latest.tar.gz wordpress-`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.tar.gz
sudo mkdir /var/www/html/example.com/public_html/
sudo mv wordpress/* ../public_html/
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/example.com/public_html
```

These are the access and error logs in my apache2. Which one should i paste?

[access and error files in apache2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtFxF.png)

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your steps on **Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS** and it works fine. Here are my steps.

```
sudo su
apt install apache2
apt install mysql-server
wget http://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz
tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz
rsync -avP ./wordpress/ /var/www/html
cd /var/www/html
rm index.html
apt install php-mysql
mysql
mysql> CREATE DATABASE wordpress;
mysql> CREATE USER wordpressuser@localhost;
mysql>  ALTER USER wordpressuser@localhost IDENTIFIED BY 'pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO wordpressuser@localhost ;
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
systemctl restart apache2
```

If it doesn't work please paste your `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, your os-release and output of `php -v`.

Comment: I have created 2 different images above. First one is log, second one is os-release and p -v output

Comment: I don't see any errors in your log. can u also paste the access_log?

Comment: i added an image showing all access log files in Apache2. Which one should i paste?

Comment: Paste the access.log.1, homelist.com-access.log and homelist.com-error_log after opening  your wordpress site once so it logs in one of the file.

Comment: this is access.log.1 bpa.st/RVMQ with this command tail -100 /var/log/apache2/access.log.1   this is homelist.com-access.log https://bpa.st/NKXA with this command tail -100 /var/log/apache2/homelistt.com-access.log    this is homelist.com-error_log https://bpa.st/UMFQ with this command tail -100 /var/log/apache2/homelistt.com-error.log I opened my linode at 06:00 pm GMT+03:00 and i browse my domain after 06:00 pm GMT+03:00

Comment: As I can see in your error logs there is something wrong with the permissions. Check ```/var/www/homelistt.com/``` has right permission. As [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451922/apache-access-denied-because-search-permissions-are-missing) you should do ```chmod 755 /var/www/homelistt.com/``` and disable selinux for testing with ```setenforce 0```.